# Paypal as payment gateway?

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card, gateway, fraud-prevention

i have to choose between several payment gateways. I heard that PayPal is quite a mess and there were several fraud-issues? Does some of you have experiences with PayPal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: question better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have.

PayPal is, in my opinion, one of the best gateways around the world, if not **the best**.

Let me answer straight to your points:

1. "Quite a mess": actually not. PayPal's APIs are **widely** documented and PayPal offers you a *sandbox* mode to test your software with fake accounts and fake money to see if your software works or not (you might find, for example, your ecommerce application tries to deliver an order the customer didn't pay for after canceling the order, etc). I don't think this stands for *quite a mess* since you can perform deep software testing
2. Fraud issues. Let me tell you that Internet frauds occur often, and it's difficult (while not impossible) to protect from them. PayPal does a lot to protect both customers and sellers from frauds. Customers are mainly protected on eBay from fraudulent sellers, but sellers are protected from chargebacks too. If a fraudulent customer buys goods from your website, the [chargeback protection](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/seller/ChargebackRisk-outside) applies. In all cases, PayPal might **freeze** part of your money during investigations.

By the way, PayPal as payment gateway enables your website to accept all credit cards, so you don't need to sign with another gateway.

## Unfortunately,

PayPal is expensive IMHO. A little too expensive...

Comment: puh, it is really expensive... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've used paypal for long time and had problems. Remember that Buyer is almost always right if you chose to work with them. Also you may get your account locked if you have unexpected amount of trx in a day. But yet, that is what most of the users use nowadays. I can only suggest you to call them and talk with them about what you are developing and what kind of sales volume are you expecting. You can reduce the risk to the minimum this way. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Tronic,

Pay pal is a Secure Transaction payment gateway used globally. Transaction is secured by VeriSign Identity Protection. It means your information is secure when you are going for the transaction. Paypal is easy to use and integration with programming language is very easy. Paypal provide a sendbox account for test your code once developed. Make sure you have to follow the terms and conditions for transaction with paypal e.g. transfer limit etc. For detailed information of integration, payment methods and creating sand box account visit to [PayPal Developer](https://www.x.com/index.jspa)